# Prototype function is not the returning the values I want to main function; what's happening?

Tags: c++, function

This is a class project but I am quite lost at this part. I am suppose to return 3 values to the main function. When I finally thought I had it, I just found out that the values I am inputting are not the values being returned. For example if I input 8 and 4 in the prototype function, when I return these values to the main function they are output as 1 and some long random number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare prototype function
void OrderInfo();

int main(int A_SpoolsOrdered, int A_SpoolStock, double A_SpecialCharges)
{
    OrderInfo();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Order Summary\n";
    cout << "==================\n\n";
    // Returning values
    cout << "items ordered:\t" << A_SpoolsOrdered << "\n"; // OrderInfo input not matching final output
    cout << "Items in stock:\t" << A_SpoolStock;           // OrderInfo input not matching final output
}

void OrderInfo()
{
    // Declare Variables
    int SpoolsOrdered, SpoolStock;
    double SpecialCharges;
    char choice;

    // Ask user for spools ordered and spools in stock and store it
    cout << "How many spools were ordered? ";
    cin >> SpoolsOrdered;                           // Value to return
    cout << "How many spools are in stock? ";
    cin >> SpoolStock;                              // Value to return

    // Ask the user if there is any additional charges
    cout << "Are special shipping charges required? <y or n>: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'y': cout << "Enter the amount of any special shipping charges: ";
        cin >> SpecialCharges;                      // Value to return
        main(SpoolsOrdered, SpoolStock, SpecialCharges);  //Attempt to return all values
        break;
    case 'n': break;
        main(SpoolsOrdered, SpoolStock, SpecialCharges);
    default: cout << "Invalaid input, run program again!\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `main` is a function that takes two parameters, an `int` and a `char **`.  Declaring it as something else, or calling it from your program, is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Then I have to look for a way around.

Comment: you have to add an intermediate function

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It is *implementation-defined* whether other signatures are allowed and it seems MSVC and GCC both actually compile this (though with warnings for GCC).

Comment: *Then I have to look for a way around* -- To be honest, the "way around" is to simply write the program as expected, and that is top-down execution, just as 100% of C++ programs are written.  What were you expecting by putting parameters in `main`, a function that gets called first by the runtime?

Comment: @walnut An implementation may support other implementation-defined definitions for `main`. If it chooses to do so (which means documenting them), then those definitions are well defined for that implementation. If you use a definition that isn't defined by the standard or explicitly supported by the implementation, the behavior is undefined (and no diagnostic is required).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was expecting to send the parameters from OrderInfo function to the main function

Comment: @Xavier How could that be, when `main` is the first function called by the C++ runtime (other than static class member functions)?  It is the entry point to your entire program, so there is no way you're going to pass parameters to `main`, unless you are passing command-line parameters.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie O M G, I am so dumb, the instructions literally meant to create another function send the parameters there and then call that function to the main function. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this backwards. The parameters of your `OrderInfo` should be `int&, int&, double&` Your prototype should look like:

```
void OrderInfo(int& A_SpoolsOrdered, int& A_SpoolStock, double& A_SpecialCharges);
```

Your `main()` function can either be `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, or `int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)`. You then call `OrderInfo` in your main function.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare prototype function
void OrderInfo(int& A_SpoolsOrdered, int& A_SpoolStock, double& A_SpecialCharges);

int main()
{
    int A_SpoolsOrdered, A_SpoolStock; 
    double A_SpecialCharges;
    OrderInfo(A_SpoolsOrdered, A_SpoolStock, A_SpecialCharges);

    cout << "\nOrder Summary\n";
    cout << "==================\n\n";

    cout << "items ordered:\t" << A_SpoolsOrdered << "\n"; 
    cout << "Items in stock:\t" << A_SpoolStock;
    getch();
}

void OrderInfo(int& SpoolsOrdered, int& SpoolStock, double& SpecialCharges);
{
    // Declare Variables
    char choice;

    // Ask user for spools ordered and spools in stock and store it
    cout << "How many spools were ordered?\n";
    cin >> SpoolsOrdered;                           // Value to return
    cout << "How many spools are in stock?\n";
    cin >> SpoolStock;                              // Value to return

    // Ask the user if there is any additional charges
    cout << "Are special shipping charges required? <y or n>:\n";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'y': cout << "Enter the amount of any special shipping charges:\n";
        cin >> SpecialCharges;                      // Value to return
        break;
    case 'n': break;
        cout << "OK, no special shipping charges.\n"
    default: cout << "Unknown value, assuming no special shipping charges.\n";
        break;
    }
}
```